# access full join on 3 tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, full-outer-join

I'm trying to perform a full outer join with 3 tables in MS access, but the problem is that access doesn't support it.

I've tried to do it with 3 left joins, but i get duplcated results for certain cases.

i am trying to join data where the name and date are the same in all 3 tables,

my query looks something like this:

```
 SELECT
    a.date, a.name, a.whatewer,
    b.date, b.name, b.whatewer,
    c.date, c.name, c.whatewer

    FROM (a LEFT JOIN b ON a.date = b.date AND a.name = b.name)
    LEFT JOIN c ON c.date = a.date AND c.name = a.name

 UNION

 SELECT
    a.date, a.name, a.whatewer,
    b.date, b.name, b.whatewer,
    c.date, c.name, c.whatewer

 FROM (b LEFT JOIN a ON a.date = b.date AND a.name = b.name)
 LEFT JOIN c ON c.date = a.date AND c.name = a.name


SELECT
   a.date, a.name, a.whatewer,
   b.date, b.name, b.whatewer,
   c.date, c.name, c.whatewer

FROM (c LEFT JOIN a ON a.date = c.date AND a.name = c.name)
LEFT JOIN b ON c.date = b.date AND c.name = b.name
```

The result i get is mostly correct but i get duplicated results when there is data in table b and c but not in a.

Instead of it all getting joined under a single name and date the result i get is one line with data from table b and then another one with combined data from b and c, as it should be.

How do i get rif of these unnecesary results?

Thank you!

EDIT:

Full code (names aren't in english, i hope you can stil understand enough to help):

```
SELECT
Nz (Nz (zajem.Datum, ak.Datum ), nk.Datum ) AS Datum,
Nz (Nz (zajem.Operater, ak.Operater ), nk.Operater ) AS Operater,
zajem.Skupni_cas_zajema AS [Skupni cas zajema (min)], 
zajem.Povprecni_cas_zajema_na_PZ AS [Povprecni cas zajema na PZ (min)], 
zajem.Stevilo_PZ AS [Stevilo zajetih PZ], 
zajem.Stevilo_poligonov AS [Stevilo poligonov], 

ak.Skupni_cas_zajema AS [Skupni cas AK (min)], 
ak.Povprecni_cas_zajema_na_PZ AS [Povprecni cas AK na PZ], 
ak.Stevilo_PZ AS [Stevilo PZ (AK)], 
ak.Stevilo_poligonov AS [Stevilo poligonov (AK)],

nk.Skupni_cas_zajema AS [Skupni cas NK (min)], 
nk.Povprecni_cas_zajema_na_PZ AS [Povprecni cas NK na PZ], 
nk.Stevilo_PZ AS [Stevilo PZ (NK)], 
nk.Stevilo_poligonov AS [Stevilo poligonov (NK)]

FROM
(tabela_ves_zajem AS zajem LEFT OUTER JOIN tabela_vse_ak AS ak ON zajem.datum = ak.datum AND zajem.operater = ak.operater) LEFT OUTER JOIN tabela_vse_nk as nk ON nk.datum = zajem.datum AND nk.operater = zajem.operater


UNION


SELECT
Nz (Nz (zajem.Datum, ak.Datum ), nk.Datum ) AS Datum,
Nz (Nz (zajem.Operater, ak.Operater ), nk.Operater ) AS Operater,
zajem.Skupni_cas_zajema AS [Skupni cas zajema (min)], 
zajem.Povprecni_cas_zajema_na_PZ AS [Povprecni cas zajema na PZ (min)], 
zajem.Stevilo_PZ AS [Stevilo zajetih PZ], 
zajem.Stevilo_poligonov AS [Stevilo poligonov], 

ak.Skupni_cas_zajema AS [Skupni cas AK (min)], 
ak.Povprecni_cas_zajema_na_PZ AS [Povprecni cas AK na PZ], 
ak.Stevilo_PZ AS [Stevilo PZ (AK)], 
ak.Stevilo_poligonov AS [Stevilo poligonov (AK)],

nk.Skupni_cas_zajema AS [Skupni cas NK (min)], 
nk.Povprecni_cas_zajema_na_PZ AS [Povprecni cas NK na PZ], 
nk.Stevilo_PZ AS [Stevilo PZ (NK)], 
nk.Stevilo_poligonov AS [Stevilo poligonov (NK)]

FROM
(tabela_vse_ak AS ak LEFT OUTER JOIN tabela_ves_zajem AS zajem ON zajem.datum = ak.datum AND zajem.operater = ak.operater) LEFT OUTER JOIN tabela_vse_nk as nk ON nk.datum = zajem.datum AND nk.operater = zajem.operater


UNION

SELECT
Nz (Nz (zajem.Datum, ak.Datum ), nk.Datum ) AS Datum,
Nz (Nz (zajem.Operater, ak.Operater ), nk.Operater ) AS Operater,
zajem.Skupni_cas_zajema AS [Skupni cas zajema (min)], 
zajem.Povprecni_cas_zajema_na_PZ AS [Povprecni cas zajema na PZ (min)], 
zajem.Stevilo_PZ AS [Stevilo zajetih PZ], 
zajem.Stevilo_poligonov AS [Stevilo poligonov], 

ak.Skupni_cas_zajema AS [Skupni cas AK (min)], 
ak.Povprecni_cas_zajema_na_PZ AS [Povprecni cas AK na PZ], 
ak.Stevilo_PZ AS [Stevilo PZ (AK)], 
ak.Stevilo_poligonov AS [Stevilo poligonov (AK)],

nk.Skupni_cas_zajema AS [Skupni cas NK (min)], 
nk.Povprecni_cas_zajema_na_PZ AS [Povprecni cas NK na PZ], 
nk.Stevilo_PZ AS [Stevilo PZ (NK)], 
nk.Stevilo_poligonov AS [Stevilo poligonov (NK)]

FROM
(tabela_vse_nk AS nk LEFT OUTER JOIN tabela_ves_zajem AS zajem ON zajem.datum = nk.datum AND zajem.operater = nk.operater) LEFT OUTER JOIN tabela_vse_ak as ak ON nk.datum = ak.datum AND nk.operater = ak.operater;
```

I am using nz(nz(zajem.datum.... to select only one date.

[Data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZEsZ.png)

All other tables are almost the same, they contain statistical data for tasks completed on certain day, each table for different task. I need to display all the data for a single day from a certain user ("operater").

I have tried the first answer but i have problems with presenting data in a nice form with it.

Thanks.

Comment: Would you provide sample data.

Answer (score 2):

Generate the list of ids first.  Then use `left join`:

```
select . . . 
from (((select name, date from a
        union -- on purpose to remove duplicates
        select name, date from b
        union -- on purpose to remove duplicates
        select name, date from b
       ) nd left join
       a
       on a.name = nd.name and a.date = nd.date
      ) left join
      b
      on b.name = nd.name and b.date = nd.date
     ) left join
     c
     on c.name = nd.name and c.date = nd.date;
```